# No read permissions even though I have set them in xubuntu?

Tags: perl, recursion, directory, readdir

I have a perl script which reads a directory and prints out the files for that directory among other things, however I am unable to do so as I have no read permissions..

```
sub func {
    my $some_dir = $_[0];
    opendir(my $DIR, $some_dir) or die "ERROR!";
    while (my $file = readdir($DIR)) {
        if (-r $file) {              # Read permissions
            print "hurray $file!\n";
            if (-d $file) {          # Directory 
               print "entering dir...\n";
               func($file);
            }
        } else {                     # No read permissions..
            print "no permissions for $file\n";
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

If I run this code with a folder structure:

```
file
folder
-file
-file
-folder
--file
--file
```

I get:

```
hurray file!
hurray folder!
entering dir..
no permissions for file
no permissions for file
no permissions for file # no idea why?? should be folder
no permissions for file
no permissions for file
```

So it only prints the files/folders that are in the starting directory, everything else has no read permissions. I tried then doing `chmod 777 file` to all of the files in the sub-directories, but I get the same result..

Any ideas?

Thanks.

EDIT - Added some things to clear up confusion.

Comment: Do you have `execute` bit set on your folder?

Comment: I believe so, doing `ls -l` shows `drwxrwxrwx` for the folder I am trying to read the contents of.

Comment: Perhaps you should try printing the file names also in the fail message, e.g. `"no permissions for '$file'\n"`.

Comment: Yep sorry, I just omitted that in my example. If I add the `$file` to the print, it shows `no permissions for file` as expected for each file (correct file names).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the documentation for `readdir` (obtained by `perldoc -f readdir`):

> Returns the next directory entry for a directory opened by "opendir".  If used in list
>   context, returns all the rest of the entries in the directory.  If there are no more
>   entries, returns an undefined value in scalar context or a null list in list context.
>
> If you're planning to filetest the return values out of a "readdir", you'd better prepend
>   the directory in question.  Otherwise, because we didn't "chdir" there, it would have
>   been testing the wrong file.

```
opendir(my $dh, $some_dir) || die "can't opendir $some_dir: $!";
@dots = grep { /^\./ && -f "$some_dir/$_" } readdir($dh);
closedir $dh;
```

Thus:

1. your `if (-r $file)` will not work, you will have to say `if (-r "$some_dir/$file")`.
2. `readdir` will also return the directories '.' and '..' and you probably are not interested in those.

Comment: Hi, just tried this with `-r $some_dir/$file` and `-r $some_dir\/$file`, same result.. EDIT! Nevermind, it worked with a bit more tinkering. Thanks!

Comment: That's because your second problem should become obvious when you carefully read the output of your script: "entering dir.."

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your working directory does not change. For example, assuming your starting directory is `/home`:

```
opendir(my $DIR, $some_dir) or die "ERROR!";    # working dir is /home
while (my $file = readdir($DIR)) {
    if (-r $file) {                             # checks for /home/$file
        print "hurray $file!\n";                # but path is /home/folder/$file
        if (-d $file) {
           print "entering dir...\n";           
           func($file);                         # enters /home/folder/$file
```

So from `/home`, the script cannot see a file `folder/file`, or, at least not the one you mean. I discovered that I had some similarly named files in my test directory and my scripts working directory which gave false positives.

The solution is to either `chdir` as appropriate, or to add the path to the file name when checking permissions. You should also compensate for the `.` (current dir) and `..` (parent dir). When I ran your script, as-is, it turned into an infinite loop.

But of course, the best solution is to use a proper module for the job: [`File::Find`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aFind):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;

my $file = shift;   # your file name
find(sub { if (-r) { print "Hurray $File::Find::name\n"; } }, $file);
```

This will recursively go through a folder and print out names of files that match the `-r` permission. If you read the documentation for `File::Find` you will find that the `find` subroutine automatically changes directory, and uses the variables:

```
$_                    # file name e.g. 'file.txt'
$File::Find::name     # full relative path e.g. 'folder/file.txt'
$File::Find::dir      # current folder name e.g. 'folder'
```

Comment: `readdir` is an exact tool which can be both good and bad. Most of the time, using `glob` is easier and more appropriate, I think. And of course, File::Find for recursion.